# Lightning Experience issue : Insufficient Privileges

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning

In the Org,  We have some users with Lightning Experience, one of them gets an "Insufficient Privileges" when accessing a VF page, while other with the same profile and role do not get the error.

The profiles and roles are same. However, the things are working fine for both user on classic but giving error for one user on creating new record :

> Insufficient Privileges
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.